# Import all files in a directory at once

Tags: javascript

I know that it is possible to import several files from one directory like this:

`import { a, b, c } from 'uselessthings/letters/'`

But is it possible to be able to somehow imoprt evreything from a folder, something like this?

`import './uselessthings/letters/*'`

And have that import evreything from the letters folder?

Comment: Do you mean all exports or all files?

Comment: All files in one directory

Comment: Your first import line only imports from one file, the `index.js`

Comment: Would this work: `import * as letters from './uselessthings/letters'`? And then `letters.a`, `letters.b`, and `letters.c`?

Comment: no, that will still only import from `index.js`, it's common to use `index.js` to group together all the exports from a folder or module

Comment: You mean those letters are constants ??? If this is the case I believe @Nathan Chu 's answer is the right one!

Comment: Those letters are files

Comment: @Rayyan my comment was for one file. Not multiple files

Comment: I want to import all files in one directory

Comment: The question @MaciejKwas pointed to answers your question. It's not possible with ESModules

Comment: Do you expect any file added to that directory to be imported automatically? Why ? @Rayyan

Comment: It turns out that there is no possible way to do what I want. This question is now a duplicate.